# netsh and blocking access to all but one WLAN

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, netsh

Currently, I'm using this:

```
netsh wlan add filter permission=block ssid="WLAN1" networktype=infrastructure
```

to hide specific WLAN SSIDs from showing up in the systray. Since there's usually more than one of them available, I've decided to put them all in a *.bat file, like so

```
@echo off
netsh wlan add filter permission=block ssid="WLAN1" networktype=infrastructure
netsh wlan add filter permission=block ssid="WLAN2" networktype=infrastructure
netsh wlan add filter permission=block ssid="AnotherWLAN" networktype=infrastructure
etc
```

and to block them all with a single click.

However, this keeps them hidden only while the blocked WLANs have those predefined SSIDs. If they change their SSID, they show up again, and I have to change my file. This isn't a problem when there's a few of them, but there's usually more than 20 showing up.

**WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO**

Is there a way for me to use netsh and, say, an if, for, or while loop, to block everything BUT the one SSID I choose? For example, in (broken) pseudo code

```
    SET myWLAN = Home                // e.g. home WLAN SSID = Home
    if (! SSID == myWLAN) {
       loop through the available SSID, and block them via netsh
    }
```

Or, would you recommend that I just go with:

```
netsh wlan add filter permission=denyall networktype=infrastructure
```

and then create a special whitelist filter for my home WLAN

```
netsh wlan delete filter permission=block ssid="myWLAN SSID" networktype=infrastructure
```

I'm pretty much new to all of this, so any help would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "allow=WLAN1"

FOR /f "tokens=3*" %%a IN ('netsh wlan show all^|findstr /i /b /L /c:"SSID "') DO (
 IF "%%b" neq "%allow%" ECHO(netsh wlan add filter permission=block ssid="%%b" networktype=infrastructure
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This batch searches the `netsh wlan show all` output for lines `/b` beginning `/i` regardless of case `/L` the literal `/c:` this constant string.

The tokenising is performed using tokens `3` and `*` (the remainder of the line) using default delimiters hich include space, so a typical SSID line filtered would be

```
SSID 5 : WLAN2
```

Token 1 is `SSID`, 2 is `5`, 3 is `:` and 4 is `WLAN2`

Since the first nominated token is `3`, that token is assigned to `%%a` and the next token is assigned to `%%b`.

Then if the token now in `%%b` does not match the `allowed` string, block it (well, the command is simply `echo`ed for debugging - change the `echo(netsh` to `netsh` to activate.

If you were to use

```
set "allow=%~1" instead of `...WLAN1` then you could run<br>
```

*thisbatch* WLAN4

to block all except `WLAN4`.

Comment: That's exactly what I had in mind. Thank you for your verbose answer, it has been more than helpful.